# output seq as one string [bash]

Tags: bash

I am trying to write test cases in a script template which runs the function `run_test_args` that takes three commands: an optional command-line argument, a string of integers each separated by a space (ex "1 2 3 4 5") that serves as the user input of the program's prompt, and a string of the expected output. Since the program is to be tested using a large sequence of numbers, I am trying to use `seq` in place of the second argument in the following form: `$(seq -s " " 100000)` to generate 1 to 100,000 separated by spaces and formatted as a string.

However, when I run the test script, the function always recognizes the first element from the output of `seq`, which is 1 in the above case, as the user input, and the second element as the expected output.

How can I take the output from `seq` and format it as all one string rather than an array of strings (which is seems to be doing given how the function is receiving arguments)?

Here is the `run_test_args` function and the tests that use the `seq` command:

```
run_test_args() {
(( ++total ))
echo -n "Running test $total..."
expected=$3
local ismac=0
date --version >/dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
   ismac=1
fi
local start=0
if (( ismac )); then
    start=$(python -c 'import time; print time.time()')
else
    start=$(date +%s.%N)
fi
(cat << ENDOFTEXT
$2
ENDOFTEXT
) > input.txt
if timeout $MAXTIME "cat input.txt | $command $1 2>&1 | tr -d '\r' > tmp.txt"; then
    echo "failure [timed out after $MAXTIME seconds]"
else
    received=$(cat tmp.txt)
    local end=$(date +%s.%N)
    if (( ismac )); then
        end=$(python -c 'import time; print time.time()')
    else
        end=$(date +%s.%N)
    fi
    local elapsed=$(echo "scale=3; $end - $start" | bc | awk '{printf "%.3f", $0}') 
    if [ "$expected" != "$received" ]; then
        echo -e "failure\n\nExpected$line\n$expected\n"
        echo -e "Received$line\n$received\n"
    else
        echo "success [$elapsed seconds]"
        (( ++num_right ))
    fi
fi
}

run_test_args "slow" $(seq 1 100000) "Enter sequence of integers, each followed by a space: Number of inversions: 0"
run_test_args "slow" $(seq -s " " 100000 -1 1) "Enter sequence of integers, each followed by a space: Number of inversions: 4999950000"

run_test_args "" $(seq -s " " 100000) "Enter sequence of integers, each followed by a space: Number of inversions: 0"
run_test_args "" $(seq -s " " 100000 -1 1) "Enter sequence of integers, each followed by a space: Number of inversions: 4999950000"
```

Comment: Show your script.

Comment: Here it is, the relevant lines are 115-116 and 132-133: https://pastebin.com/6CLdH1N1

Comment: The shortest possible code necessary to reproduce a problem should be *included in the question itself*. See the docs on building a [mcve], and entry #1 in the "some questions are still off-topic" list at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: In general, though, `s=$(seq ...)` *does* assign just one string, and if you use it in quotes, as `"$s"`, it'll remain so. If you don't quote everywhere you need to... well, there's your problem. (Similarly, `printf '%s\n' "$(seq 1 10)"` passes one string to `printf` with all your numbers, but `printf '%s\n' $(seq 1 10)`, without the quotes, passes each number as a separate argument).

Comment: Exactly what I said in the comment above -- you can't leave out the quotes. `"$(seq ...)"`, not `$(seq ...)` alone.

Comment: See http://shellcheck.net/ for some automated testing on your scripts.

Comment: BTW -- in general, `printf` should be used instead of `echo -e` or `echo -n`. `printf '%s\n' "first line: $var1" "second line: $var2"` is much safer, as only the format string is evaluated for escapes and such, and your variable contents (in subsequent arguments) will be literal; moreover, `echo -e` isn't permitted by the POSIX spec for `echo` -- meaning it's one of the very few places where bash isn't just extending the standard but breaking it outright. See the spec @ http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html, particularly APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections.

Comment: ...I'd also suggest encapsulating your date logic: `if date --version >/dev/null 2>&1; then getdate() { date +%s.%N; }; else getdate() { python -c 'import time; print time.time()'; }; fi` or such, then just `start=$(getdate)` and `end=$(getdate)` thereafter -- and no `ismac` flag needed.

Comment: btw, do note that there's a limit on maximum allowed (command line length + environment variable size). A big sequence runs the risk of hitting that limit, if you pass it to an external command (vs a shell function, which doesn't call `execv` and thus isn't subject to the limit).